# DropDown menu (SubMenu) on clicking ImageButton as shown in figure

Tags: android, submenu

Can anybody help me that how to get the submenu when imagebutton is clicked as like shown in the image below.
Thank you in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is PopupWindow

you should take a look on this page
http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/03/example-of-using-popupwindow.html

Answer (score 1):

You create an view in xml with the required submenu options and during the onClick of the menu options u inflate the view and display it. It will work fine.
I suggest u use fragments to make the code re-useable.